# Custom bash prompt is buggy

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

I followed some articles on how to change the prompt, I've got the result I was looking for, but when the cursor reach the end of the screen it doesn't go new line and `tab` completion it's strange.

```
# ~/.bashrc

# colorful, with time, history id and path (also in window title)
export PS1="\[\e]0;\w\a\]\e[1;36m\t-\! - \w>\e[m "
```

Anybody have got a clue on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PS1 problem, messing up CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111840/ps1-problem-messing-up-cli)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colour setting escape sequences need to be enclosed in `\[` and `\]` in order to tell bash readline that they don't contribute to the length of the line. This should do it:

```
PS1="\[\e]0;\w\a\e[1;36m\]\t-\! - \w>\[\e[m\] "
```

Comment: Thank you @ak2, that seems to have solved the problem, a good relief...