# changing bash output format results in strange behaviour

Tags: bash, customization, prompt

I already changed my bash output format to something like this:

[image]

which I am very happy with. I achieved this by adding this code to the `.bashrc`:

```
set_PS1()
{
    local RESET=$(tput sgr0 )
    local BOLD=$(tput bold )
    local RED=$(tput setaf 1 )
    local GREEN=$(tput setaf 2 )
    local YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3 )
    local BLUE=$(tput setaf 4 )
    local CYAN=$(tput setaf 6 )

    local WHOAMI='\u'
    local WHERE='\w'
    local HOSTNAME='\h'
    local TIME='\D{%H:%M:%S}'


     exit_code_prompt() {
        local EXIT_CODE=$?
        local RED=$(tput setaf 1 )
        local GREEN=$(tput setaf 2 )
        if [ $EXIT_CODE -ne 0 ]; then
            echo -e "$RED$BOLD\xE2\x9C\x98 $EXIT_CODE \xE2\x86\x92"  # Red cross mark symbol
        else
            echo -e "$GREEN$BOLD\xE2\x9C\x93 \xE2\x86\x92"  # Green checkmark symbol
        fi
    }

    local LINE_1="$BOLD$YELLOW$TIME $CYAN$WHOAMI$BLUE@$CYAN$HOSTNAME$RESET$BOLD":" $BLUE$WHERE$RESET"
    local LINE_2="$BOLD\$(exit_code_prompt) "$RESET$BOLD' \$: '$RESET


    PS1="$LINE_1\n$LINE_2"

    unset -f set_PS1
}

set_PS1
```

My problem was that if I had a comand that is longer than one line it didn't do a linebreak but instead it overwrote the content from the same line (only in visual representation ofc):

[image]

Now when I delete the complete command, it deletes a part of the bash prompt as well:

[image]

This could be solved by adding `\[` and `\]`:

```
    local LINE_1="\[$BOLD$YELLOW$TIME $CYAN$WHOAMI$BLUE@$CYAN$HOSTNAME$RESET$BOLD":" $BLUE$WHERE$RESET\]"
    local LINE_2="\[$BOLD\$(exit_code_prompt) "$RESET$BOLD' \$: \]'$RESET
```

Another problem persists though. When I cycle through the last used commands it deletes the prompt sign `$`:

[image]

how do I solve this issue?

I already looked into using `zsh` but I didn't want to loose the `bash` functionality like keyboard shortcuts that I already got used to...

**UPDATE:** below is my updated code, that still doesn't work:

```
set_PS1()
{
    local Reset="\\[$(tput sgr0 )\\]"
    local Bold="\\[$(tput bold )\\]"
    local Red="\\[$(tput setaf 1 )\\]"
    local Green="\\[$(tput setaf 2 )\\]"
    local Yellow="\\[$(tput setaf 3 )\\]"
    local Blue="\\[$(tput setaf 4 )\\]"
    local MagentaBG="\\[$(tput setab 5 )\\]"
    local Cyan="\\[$(tput setaf 6 )\\]"

    local Whoami='\u'
    local Where='\w'
    local Hostname='\h'
    local Time='\D{%H:%M:%S}'
    local Exit_Code="$?"

    exit_code_prompt() {
        local Exit_Code="$?"
        local Red="$(tput setaf 1 )"
        local Green="$(tput setaf 2 )"
        if [ $Exit_Code -ne 0 ]; then
            printf "$Red\xE2\x9C\x98 $Exit_Code \xE2\x86\x92 " # Red cross mark symbol
        else
            printf "$Green\xE2\x9C\x93 \xE2\x86\x92 " # Green checkmark symbol
        fi
    }

    local Line_1="$Bold$Yellow$Time $Cyan$Whoami$Blue@$Cyan$Hostname$Reset$Bold":" $Blue$Where$Reset"
    local Line_2="$Bold\$(exit_code_prompt)$Reset$Bold \$: $Reset"

    PS1="$Line_1\n$Line_2"

    unset -f set_PS1
}

set_PS1
```

I will have the same problem as before. Text that is longer than one line will appear on the start of the same line and overwrite. Cycling through commands results in either the deletion of a part of the prompt or in an visual bug that shows part of a previous command that is not accessible.

**UPDATE 2**: The problem definitely lies in the `exit_code_prompt` function. when i delete it from `$Line_2` everything works as expected.

Comment: might have found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48240/custom-bash-prompt-is-buggy)
ecaping the prompt with `\[` and `\]` works for now

Comment: If you have, please consider posting an answer.

Comment: @terdon I edited the original question but it's not fully solved thats why I didn't post an answer

Comment: Don't wrap the whole thing in that. Only wrap the color codes, not the prompt sign or the spaces

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then [wonder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) [why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552) your script is [broken](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114596/4667).

Comment: Do `printf '%s' "$var"` rather than `printf "$var"` to print the contents of a variable as-is. For example, `printf "$Green\xE2\x9C\x93 \xE2\x86\x92 "` should be `printf '%s\xE2\x9C\x93 \xE2\x86\x92 ' "$Green"` or similar so `printf` doesn't interpret the contents of `$Green` as formatting instructions and you don't need to double-escape due to `"` instead of `'` delimiters.

Comment: Nit-pick: Don't use negative logic if you can avoid it. You have `if [ $Exit_Code -ne 0 ]; then Red; else Green; fi` so ask yourself under what condition you use `Green` and the answer is "it is NOT true that Exit_code is NOT equal to 0", i.e. a double negative. Positive logic is always easier to understand than negative (esp double negative!) so you should have written that as `if [ $Exit_Code -eq 0 ]; then Green; else Red; fi` instead. Also consider using the modern `if (( Exit_code == 0 ))` syntax instead of the old, clunky `if [ $Exit_Code -eq 0 ]`.

Comment: @EdMorton that helped with the deletion of parts of the prompt while cycling through the last used commands.
now there is only the thing left where there are leftovers from previous commands like `18:28:57 reneas@reneas-kubuntu-yoga: ~
✓ →  $: echcd` where I can only move my cursor to just before the `cd` and  the `ech` is a leftover from a previous `echo` command

Comment: It sounds like the problem you asked about in your question has been solved and then an additional problem has also been solved. Please [accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) you got to your original problem then ask a new question that's only about whatever your current problem is as [Chameleon Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) atre strongly discouraged.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the hint! I'm fairly new here and not completely aware of all the "etiquette". The new question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504292/custom-bash-prompt-has-leftovers-from-previous-commands) if you have any other ideas on how to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PS1 problem, messing up CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111840/ps1-problem-messing-up-cli)

Comment: the answer from @glennjackman was already pretty good :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @Daniel's advice, use

```sh
    local RESET="\\[$(tput sgr0 )\\]"
```

And similar with all the other colour codes.

From [6.9 Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) in the manual:

```
\[
    Begin a sequence of non-printing characters. This could be used to
    embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt.

\]
    End a sequence of non-printing characters.
```

---

Looping back to your question:

> When I cycle through the last used commands it deletes the prompt sign

That's because without the `\[` and `\]` to wrap the control sequences, bash cannot correctly calculate the length of your prompt.

Comment: even after implementing your suggestion (where I also don't really understand why there are two \\\) the problem persists. When I cycle through the last used commands it not only deletes the prompt sign but almost all of the prompt...

Comment: There are 2 ```\``` because the string is within double quotes so the shell can expand `$(tput sgr0 )` but that means the shell will also interpret/strip a ```\```, so `\[` would become `[`, and so if you want `\[` left after shell interpretation then you need to add a ```\``` for the shell to consume - `\\[` will become `\[` after shell interpretation.

Comment: @EdMorton okay thanks for the explanation! Strangely enough it's also working with only one ``\``. Any idea why said problem is still not gone?

Comment: I notice at `local LINE_2="$BOLD\$(exit_code_prompt) "$RESET$BOLD' \$: '$RESET` you have `$RESET$BOLD` and `$RESET` unquoted so maybe that's the problem, or maybe your use of all-upper-case variable names (don't do that - see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)!) is clobbering some environment variable, idk.

Comment: @EdMorton By now I've already corrected my Variables to look like `$Bold` and `local Line_2="$Bold\$(exit_code_prompt)$Reset$Bold \$: $Reset"`
But still I have the weird formatting error. I updated the question to show my current code.

Comment: You're calling `printf` incorrectly. You're doing `printf "$var"` when you should be doing `printf '%s' "$var"`. The former is using `$var` as the **format** string for printf, not the data string, and so various chars/strings it contains will be interpreted as formatting instructions. Don't do that. Any time you want a string printed as-is do `printf '%s' "$var"`, not `printf "$var"`. Idk if that's the cause of your problem of course. I added a comment under your question about that as we've strayed far off Glenn's answer now.