# How can I properly make a bash prompt with error colors and emoji?

Tags: command-line, bash, customization, prompt

After solving the first [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504038/changing-bash-output-format-results-in-strange-behaviour?noredirect=1#comment2638825_1504038) with my custom prompt I still have another one left.

When I cycle through my last used commands via the arrow-up and arrow-down keys I will sometimes have some characters from a previous command stay visible although the are not accessible nor actually in the commandline. They are just a visual bug very annoying and confusing.

Looks like this:
[image]

Here I went a bit up in the command history and then back down to the current (empty) prompt and typed `echo`. the `pip i` (coming from a previous `pip install` command) is not accessible with my cursor. It's visible there but not actually existent.

My `.bashrc` has this code for customizing the prompt:

```
set_PS1()
{
    local Reset="\\[$(tput sgr0 )\\]"
    local Bold="\\[$(tput bold )\\]"
    local Red="\\[$(tput setaf 1 )\\]"
    local Green="\\[$(tput setaf 2 )\\]"
    local Yellow="\\[$(tput setaf 3 )\\]"
    local Blue="\\[$(tput setaf 4 )\\]"
    local MagentaBG="\\[$(tput setab 5 )\\]"
    local Cyan="\\[$(tput setaf 6 )\\]"

    local Whoami='\u'
    local Where='\w'
    local Hostname='\h'
    local Time='\D{%H:%M:%S}'
    local Exit_Code="$?"

    exit_code_prompt() {
        local Exit_Code="$?"
        local Red="$(tput setaf 1 )"
        local Green="$(tput setaf 2 )"
        if (($Exit_Code == 0 )); then
            printf '%s\xE2\x9C\x93 \xE2\x86\x92 ' "$Green" # Green checkmark symbol
        else
            printf '%s\xE2\x9C\x98 %s \xE2\x86\x92 ' "$Red" "$Exit_Code" # Red cross mark symbol and exit code
        fi
    }

    local Line_1="$Bold$Yellow$Time $Cyan$Whoami$Blue@$Cyan$Hostname$Reset$Bold":" $Blue$Where$Reset"
    local Line_2="$Bold\$(exit_code_prompt)$Reset$Bold \$: $Reset"
    #local Line_2="$Bold \$: $Reset"

    PS1="$Line_1\n$Line_2"

    unset -f set_PS1
}

set_PS1
```

I already narrowed the problem down to the `exit_code_prompt` function since the problem doesn't appear if I remove it from `$Line_2`

**EDIT:**
When I put the color definitions inside of the function into brackets like on the outside like this:

```
exit_code_prompt() {
        local Exit_Code="$?"
        local Red="\\[$(tput setaf 1 )\\]"
        local Green="\\[$(tput setaf 2 )\\]"
        if (($Exit_Code == 0 )); then
            printf '%s\xE2\x9C\x93 \xE2\x86\x92 ' "$Green" # Green checkmark symbol
        else
            printf '%s\xE2\x9C\x98 %s \xE2\x86\x92 ' "$Red" "$Exit_Code" # Red cross mark symbol and exit code
        fi
    }
```

I get this result:

[image]

Same result if I put only single backslashes `\` 
Plus the inital problem is still there!

Comment: Why are the `local {Red,Green}=...` different inside and outside?

Comment: @DanielT The only difference are the ``\\[`` and ```\\]`` brackets if I'm seeing it correctly. When I tried putting them in brackets inside the function, they ended up being printed along the checkmark. This was the case for single quotes `'`, for double quotes `"`, for single backslash ``\`` and for double backslash ``\\`` and all combinations of the above. Theoretically I could remove the outer ones since they don't get used anyways.

Comment: Ctrl+F `local Red="$(tput setaf 1 )"` . You completely forgot the backslash you added to the other one

Comment: @DanielT see my comment above and the question edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### New solution

It turns out it's actually possible to do this with just `PS1` and not `PROMPT_COMMAND`. We don't need to set any additional global variables. Here's a one-liner:

`PS1=$'\e[1;33m\\t \e[36m\u\e[34m@\e[36m\h\e[;1m: \e[34m\w\n \[\b\e[;1;31m✘\] ${?/#0/\[\b\b\e[32m✓ \]}${?/#[1-9]*/  }\[\b→\e[;1m\] \$: \[\e[m\]'`

The improvements from my original solution below are the following:

- Only the last line needs `\[\]`
- I expanded the `tput` to `\e[...m`. This is compatible across Ubuntu and is not a concern because the default colored `.bashrc` also does this
- Successive `\e[Xm\e[Ym` collapse into `\e[X;Ym`, and the previous bold doesn't always need to be reset
- `\D{%H:%M:%S}` = `\\t`
- Unknown `\X` sequences don't need the backslash escaped
- I rely on `$?` being `0` or positive without leading zeroes: `?/#0*/` = `?/#0/`
- `${?/#[1-9]*/  }\[\b` inserts a space then any character (currently space) for non-zero, and any character (currently 0) for zero. Then the additional character is deleted, to implement inserting exactly one space only for non-zero.
- `[1-9]*` is a glob that means any digit 1-9 then anything, not a RegEx that means any number of the preceding
- `✘\] ${?/#0/\[\b\b\e[32m✓ \]}` always prints the red cross mark symbol first. If zero, we go back and replace it with a green checkmark. If non-zero we print the error code instead

#### Guided solution

Here is a working prompt:

```bash
set_PS1() {
    local Exit_Code="$?"
    local Reset="\\[$(tput sgr0 )\\]"
    local Bold="\\[$(tput bold )\\]"
    local Red="\\[$(tput setaf 1 )\\]"
    local Green="\\[$(tput setaf 2 )\\]"
    local Yellow="\\[$(tput setaf 3 )\\]"
    local Blue="\\[$(tput setaf 4 )\\]"
    local MagentaBG="\\[$(tput setab 5 )\\]"
    local Cyan="\\[$(tput setaf 6 )\\]"

    local Whoami='\u'
    local Where='\w'
    local Hostname='\h'
    local Time='\D{%H:%M:%S}'
    # Emoji are multi-byte, but shells think 1 byte = 1 character
    # We add a 1-character space, then enable color-code mode to ignore
    # the upcoming emoji, then backspace to draw the emoji on top of the space.
    local emoji_start=$' \\[\b'
    local emoji_end=$'\\]'

    if (($Exit_Code == 0 )); then
        local exit_code_prompt="$Green$emoji_start"$'\xE2\x9C\x93'"$emoji_end" # Green checkmark symbol
    else
        local exit_code_prompt="$Red$emoji_start"$'\xE2\x9C\x98'"$emoji_end $Exit_Code" # Red cross mark symbol and exit code
    fi


    local Line_1="$Bold$Yellow$Time $Cyan$Whoami$Blue@$Cyan$Hostname$Reset$Bold":" $Blue$Where$Reset"
    local Line_2="$Bold$exit_code_prompt $emoji_start"$'\xE2\x86\x92'"$emoji_end$Reset$Bold \\$: $Reset"
    #local Line_2="$Bold \$: $Reset"

    PS1="$Line_1\\n$Line_2"
}

# We need to expand exit_code_prompt BEFORE PS1 prompt string expansion (see shopt promptvars in man bash)
# so we want to move it to PROMPT_COMMAND which runs earlier.
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_PS1
```

- `PS1` undergoes prompt expansion then substitution, so we need `PROMPT_COMMAND`
- This leaks the `set_PS1` global, but you already have the `exit_code_prompt` global leaked
- `"\$"` needs to be `"\\$"` so it undergoes prompt evaluation instead of immediately
- Emojis are multi-byte and need to be wrapped as well, except this time we need to insert a fake space because they are 1-character wide unlike 0-character wide color codes
- `printf` is unnecessarily complicated when you could just do `$''`

Now <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> command history works. Scrolling a multiline prompt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> also jumps to the correct position now.

Here are some examples:

- Prompt demo:

  [image: prompt demo]
- Long string:

  [image: long string]
- Long string then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>:

  [image: long string then ←]
- `pip install` then `echo`:

  [image: pip install then echo]
- `echo` then <kbd>↑</kbd> in history:

  [image: echo then ↑ in history]

Comment: I was thinking it was the multi-byte characters, but then you went ahead and solved it. Kudos!

Comment: works like a charm, thanks for this! I still don't completely understand why it behaves like this but I guess that's fine :)

Comment: wow nice one! this is definitely a nice variation, wish i could upvote again x) only issue I'm having with this is that on a failed command the tip of the red arrow is cut off

Comment: @reneas Can you edit the question with a screenshot of the cut off arrow? You could also switch the gnome-terminal font to JetBrains Mono or another font that has 1-character-wide arrows

Comment: edited your question with adding of the screenshot. I'm using the `Hack` font in `Konsole` but also after changing the font to `JetBrains Mono` the arrow is still cut off

Comment: @reneas Please edit your question not the answer next time. In your https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfBuI.png , the arrow is not the JetBrains Mono at https://fonts.google.com/specimen/JetBrains+Mono?preview.text=%E2%86%92 . Please make sure you did `sudo apt install fonts-jetbrains-mono ; sudo fc-cache -fv ; fc-cache -fv` and set to another font then set the font to this one in terminal. If it still doesn't work please ask another question and include ```cat /proc/`pidof gnome-terminal-server`/maps | grep ttf```

Comment: also after installing the other font it looks the same.
I dont't think I will ask another question, since the other version (the longer one) works well and is also more human readable so i can understand better what's happening there.
thank for your help @DanielT!!

Comment: @DanielT I created a new question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1505875/symbol-gets-cut-off-in-custom-bash-prompt) if you want to check it out!