# Symbol gets cut off in custom bash prompt

Tags: bash, customization, prompt

I am using a custom bash prompt with this command that was an answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1504292/how-can-i-properly-make-a-bash-prompt-with-error-colors-and-emoji) question:
It looks like this:

```
PS1=$'\e[1;33m\\t \e[36m\u\e[34m@\e[36m\h\e[;1m: \e[34m\w\n \[\b\e[;1;31m✘\] ${?/#0/\[\b\b\e[32m✓ \]}${?/#[1-9]*/  }\[\b→\e[;1m\]  \$: \[\e[m\]'
```

With a successful command (`exit code = 0`) it looks like this:
[image]

With an unsuccessful command (`exit code != 0`) it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the red arrow is cut off, which is not really a problem but still annoying. No matter which Monospace font I'm using, the result is always a cutoff arrow.

My initial prompt command looked something like this:

```
set_PS1()
{
    local Exit_Code="$?"
    local Reset="\\[$(tput sgr0 )\\]"
    local Bold="\\[$(tput bold )\\]"
    local Red="\\[$(tput setaf 1 )\\]"
    local Green="\\[$(tput setaf 2 )\\]"
    local Yellow="\\[$(tput setaf 3 )\\]"
    local Blue="\\[$(tput setaf 4 )\\]"
    local MagentaBG="\\[$(tput setab 5 )\\]"
    local Cyan="\\[$(tput setaf 6 )\\]"

    local Whoami='\u'
    local Where='\w'
    local Hostname='\h'
    local Time='\D{%H:%M:%S}'
    # Emoji are multi-byte, but shells think 1 byte = 1 character
    # We add a 1-character space, then enable color-code mode to ignore
    # the upcoming emoji, then backspace to draw the emoji on top of the space.
    local emoji_start=$' \\[\b'
    local emoji_end=$'\\]'

    if (($Exit_Code == 0 )); then
        local exit_code_prompt="$Green$emoji_start"$'\xE2\x9C\x93'"$emoji_end $emoji_start"$'\xE2\x86\x92'"$emoji_end" # Green checkmark symbol
    else
        local exit_code_prompt="$Red$emoji_start"$'\xE2\x9C\x98'"$emoji_end $Exit_Code $emoji_start"$'\xE2\x86\x92'"$emoji_end" # Red cross mark symbol and exit code
    fi


    local Line_1="$Bold$Yellow$Time $Cyan$Whoami$Blue@$Cyan$Hostname$Reset$Bold":" $Blue$Where$Reset"
    local Line_2="$Bold$exit_code_prompt $Reset$Bold \\$: $Reset"
    #local Line_2="$Bold \$: $Reset"

    PS1="$Line_1\\n$Line_2"
}

# We need to expand exit_code_prompt BEFORE PS1 prompt string expansion (see shopt promptvars in man bash)
# so we need to move it to PROMPT_COMMAND which runs earlier.
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_PS1
```

with this setup the arrow is shown normally **but** it doesn't show when I'm inside a loaded `python venv` which is a no-go. Therefore I'm using the short version now which has the cutoff arrow...

**UPDATE:**
When using the `DejaVu Sans Mono` font the arrow is not cut off. In fact the amount that is cut off changes with each different used font, some ahve more some have less and `DejaVu Sans Mono` seems to have no cutoff as can be seen here:

[image]

Comment: The arrow is cut off because it is not monospace, i.e. exactly one terminal column wide. JetBrains Mono provides a monospace arrow, but the default font doesn't. It works on Konsole 23.10. I might test on 22.04 when I get around to it

Comment: Maybe I just have to wait for the 24.04 release and everything will be fine...? To be honest I don't really like the JetBrains font so I would rather stick to Hack. DejaVu seems to be pretty similar though so I might just stick with that

Comment: That might not work because it doesn't have a monospace `→`. But as a workaround, how about replacing that emoji with the two regular ASCII character sequence `->` ?